# How to implement an iterator of mutable references to the values in the right edges of a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: rust

I implemented a simple Binary Search Tree in Rust (following CIS 198, it's great), and for learning I'm doing iterators that just run through the right edges.

I could not implement an iterator that gives mutable references. I tried a lot of ways, but none were accepted by Rust compiler. The code I need help is the one below ([while I made a gist with the complete code here](https://gist.github.com/astamatto/ad05770ec285c07ae046cbcdd3e53345)):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Tree<T>(Option<Box<Node<T>>>);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    left: Tree<T>,
    right: Tree<T>,
}

// MUTABLE BORROW STRUCT
pub struct IterMut<'a, T: 'a> {
    next: &'a mut Tree<T>,
}

// MUTABLE BORROW NEXT (I'M STUCK HERE, NOTHING WORKS)
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // 1 try: cannot infer lifetime
        self.next.0.as_mut().map(|node| {
            self.next = &mut node.right;
            &mut node.elem
        })

        // 2 try: node.right, node.elem does not live long enough
        self.next.0.take().map(|node| {
            self.next = &mut node.right;
            &mut node.elem
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the type of the field `IterMut::next` to `Option<&'a mut Node<T>>`:

```
pub struct IterMut<'a, T: 'a> {
    next: Option<&'a mut Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.take().map(|node| {
            self.next = node.right.0.as_mut().map(|node| &mut **node);
            &mut node.elem
        })

    }
}
```

You can find more useful information about the implementation of the mutable iterator for recursive data structures [in the IterMut chapter of *Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/second-iter-mut.html).

Comment: Excellent link! It had not occurred to me that one could write this safely (of course, the OP's tree structure is lacking the back reference needed for full iteration).

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize that by using Tree<T> I was using an unnecessary Box. 

I still cannot fully visualize the borrow rules in action, but in the share borrow iterator (&T) I did not caught the unnecessary Box because my code worked - probably because there's no problem in immutable borrowing more than once.

Comment: Wow, that was buried in the original question — I read it multiple times over many months and never noticed it. I've edited the question to be more obvious. Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you cannot split `self` into 2 mutable objects (one for the `Item`, one for `self` itself) without using some unsafe code.

Comment: It should work. This works too: `let mut x = Box::new((3, 5)); let next = &mut x; let (ref mut a, ref mut b) = *ref_mut.deref_mut();` (strangely it doesn't work with `**ref_mut` on the rhs...). It should be safe and should work without unsafe code, but I too can't get it to work right now :/